# Access to an HDD data on another PC

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

I will install on a new PC Windows 10 on a SSD, after the boot is over, can I put my current HDD in the new PC? Will be able to access all the data I have on the current desktop, etc.?

Comment: You can connect as many storage devices as your PC supports.

Comment: You omitted some of the details that would help us give you a definitive answer, but yes, as long as that old hard drive wasn't encrypted it should work rather easily.

Comment: I was worried because the old drive have a operating system on it, but it looks like it is not a problem, right?

Comment: @Run5k - Even if FDS or EFS was used it the data can still be accessed depending on variables.

Comment: @Ramhound, yes, absolutely... that's why I was emphasizing some of the missing details.  Typically, you should be fine.  We do this every day when we re-image/upgrade physical machines on our domain.

Comment: I think I remember some issue with moving a GPT disk to another computer, but that issue may be that you cannot use it in the new computer to boot. not sure though...

Answer (score 0):

There sure is multiple ways to do this.

First one, you can simply take your old HDD and plug it into your new PC.
Look on Google for a complete procedure, you might need a PATA or SATA Cable, depending on your Motherboard & HDD.

---

Second, you can turn both PCs on and Access to your old PC by Network.
Simply start "Explorer.exe", then type `\\*NameOfThePCHere*\C$`

From there, you can explore your whole HDD. You might want to go to 
`\\*NameOfThePCHere*\C$\Users\*YourUserNameHere*\Desktop`

---

These are the fastest ways that came to my mind.

Hope it helped ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to make you aware, aside from the answers already mentioned by Darksoulpk68 and in the comments above, you have the option to use a USB bridge to connect your hard drive to your computer. I have something like this and it works fine: [https://www.amazon.com/Sabrent-Converter-Activity-Support-USB-DSC5/dp/B000HJ99DI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HJ99DI)

If you want permanent access to the old drive, then it is probably better to install it internally as mentioned above. But for occasional access, this might do the trick for you.